# What is the point in keeping dimens file on mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi variation?

Tags: android, layout, dimensions, probability-density

What is the point keeping dimens file on mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi variation? Declaring values in DP in dimens file should calculate the values based on the density right? I am confused!

Answer (score 1):

You still might want to have different dimensions for spacing and size for different screens.

A common use case is to reduce spacings on smaller screens, so that more content is visible at the same time.

Comment: @so if i specify 16dp for margin in default folder then should I create xxxhdpi and mention 64dp? Doesn't dp conversion will not take place in xxxhdpi device automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of devices has the same screen different size but different densities (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi).

Diversifying your view's size by using multiple dimen files make your layout shown in probably way in all devices.